# NO bit stream picker in video js for HLS

Tags: javascript, video.js, http-live-streaming, adaptive-bitrate

i am trying to run HLS manifest with `.m3u8` extension in `video.js` which runs smooth with my code i was wondering if there is any way to extract bit-streams and show them on control bar of player.so that a user could switch between bit rates?

i tried using https://github.com/streamroot/videojs-quality-picker plugin but it was throwing this error again and again

> Uncaught TypeError: videojs(...).qualityPickerPlugin is not a function

any help regarding this issue would be really appriciated thanks

```
<video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264" data-setup="{}" autoplay>
  <source src="legend_hls/legend_playlist.m3u8">

  <p class="vjs-no-js">
    To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
    <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
  </p>
</video>
<script>
  videojs('my-video').qualityPickerPlugin();
</script>
```